# Sum of all elements after first 0 in array

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops, sum

I need to sum all elements in array that going after first 0 in this array.

---

I have this code but it doesn't work.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int array[5]{ 1,5,0,2,4 }, i, sum = 0;

    for (i = 0; i > 4; i++) {
        if (array[i] == 0) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            continue;
        }
        
    }
    for (i; i > 4; i++) {
        sum = sum + array[i];
    }

    cout << "Sum of all elements in array after first zirrow is " << sum;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: review how `for` loop conditions work. `i > 4` is not what you want.

Comment: The condition being true means "keep looping", false means "stop".

Comment: *Sum of all elements after first 0 in array* -- [C++ is wonderful](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5a49c6841486359)

Comment: `else { continue; }` is unnecessary. Loops continue by default.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You can do even better with `std::begin(array)` and `std::end(array)`.

Comment: Done any debugging yet (even with pen and paper possible)? What were your findings?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::find` to get an iterator to the first 0, and then you can use `std::accumulate` to sum up the elements till the end:

```
auto from = std::find(std::begin(array), std::end(array), 0);

int sum = std::accumulate(from, std::end(array), 0);
```

Comment: No need to use magic numbers with `std::begin()` and `std::end()` at hand.

Comment: @Evg Absolutely right. Edited, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

`i > 4` should be `i < 5` in both loops. With `i > 4` you don't even go into the loops because 0 > 4 is false.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there are 5 elements in your array so you need to iterate from 0 to 4. So the condition will be `i<=4` or `i<5` not `i> 4`. As you start with i = 0, you are never going inside the loop. as the condition is false here cause i=0 is false when you set the condition `i>4`. Other things are okay except the loop condition.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int array[5]{ 1,5,0,2,4 }, i, sum = 0;

    for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        if (array[i] == 0) {
            break;
        }        
    }
    for ( ; i <= 4; i++) {
        sum = sum + array[i];
    }

    cout << "Sum of all elements in array after first zirrow is " << sum;

    return 0;
}
```

or, if you like to use `i < 5`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int array[5]{ 1,5,0,2,4 }, i, sum = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (array[i] == 0) {
            break;
        }   
    }
    for ( ; i < 5; i++) {
        sum = sum + array[i];
    }

    cout << "Sum of all elements in array after first zirrow is " << sum;

    return 0;
}
```

Note that i removed the `else { continue }` as it is unecessary since the for loop coninues anyway.

Comment: `i < 5` is more idiomatic than `i <= 4`. Since the size of the array is 5 it's easier to understand if you repeat that number in the for loop.

Comment: thanks for valuable comment. i have already updated my ans

Answer (score 1):

The condition of the for loops

```
for (i = 0; i > 4; i++) {
```

and

```
for (i; i > 4; i++) {
```

is wrong. As in the first for loop the variable `i` is initialized by `0` then the condition `i > 4` at once will be evaluated to false and this loop and the following loop will not be executed.

Pay attention to that it is a bad idea to use magic numbers like `4` in the condition of the loops.

Also using the break and continue statements in a simple loop is a bad style of programming that makes code more complicated.

It is better to declare the variable `sum`  as having the type `long long int` to reduce the risk of overflow because in general the array can be initialized with different values.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int array[] = { 1, 5, 0, 2, 4 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( array ) / sizeof( *array );
    
    size_t i = 0;
    
    while ( i < N && array[i] != 0 ) ++i;
    
    long long int sum = 0;
    
    if ( i != N )
    {
        while ( ++i < N )
        {
            sum += array[i];
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Sum of all elements in array after first zirrow is "
              << sum << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Sum of all elements in array after first zirrow is 6
```

As you are learning C++ then it will be useful to know how to do the same task using standard C++ algorithms.

Here is a demonstrative program that does the same task with using standard C++ algorithms.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

int main() 
{
    int array[] = { 1, 5, 0, 2, 4 };
    
    auto it = std::find( std::begin( array ), std::end( array ), 0 );
    
    long long int sum = 0;
    
    if ( it != std::end( array ) )
    {
        sum = std::accumulate( std::next( it ), std::end( array ), 0ll );
    }
    
    std::cout << "Sum of all elements in array after first zirrow is "
              << sum << '\n';
              
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is the same as shown above.

```
Sum of all elements in array after first zirrow is 6
```